# Very slow OS loading speed

Tags: boot, 18.04, laptop

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop and after i put my login password it always takes from 2 to 10 minutes to actually load up to the desktop. I don't think that's a normal behavior. How to troubleshoot that and how to fix it?
The Laptop had/has FreeDos boot.
 
**EDIT:**

**Specs:**

```
description: Computer
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smp vsyscall32
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       physical id: 0
     *-memory
          description: System memory
          physical id: 0
          size: 7846MiB
     *-cpu
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 1
          bus info: cpu@0
          size: 2200MHz
          capacity: 4100MHz
          width: 64 bits
```

Also i have two disks: (Ubuntu is installed on SSD)

```
NAME        FSTYPE     SIZE MOUNTPOINT                     LABEL
loop0       squashfs  88,5M /snap/core/7270                
loop1       squashfs     4M /snap/gnome-calculator/406     
loop2       squashfs  1008K /snap/gnome-logs/61            
loop3       squashfs  54,4M /snap/core18/1066              
loop4       squashfs  42,8M /snap/gtk-common-themes/1313   
loop5       squashfs 149,9M /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/67       
loop6       squashfs  14,8M /snap/gnome-characters/296     
loop7       squashfs   3,7M /snap/gnome-system-monitor/100 
sda                  931,5G                                
└─sda1      ext4     931,5G                                data
nvme0n1              119,2G                                
└─nvme0n1p1 ext4     119,2G /
```

#### Time to load to desktop after login from my disk:

First try - 30 seconds 
Second try - Didn't load up after 10 mins (force restarted it)
Third try - Again around 30 seconds 
Fourth try - Around 1 minute 
Fifth try - around 30 seconds

#### Time to load from live USB after clicking "Try ubuntu"

Only 1 try - around 3 seconds.

Also from time to time when i shutdown the computer it shows this: 
[image]
[image]

And always when i shutdown the laptop it shows this: 
[image]

Additional info after running: `systemd-analyze blame`

```
         15.015s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      4.907s plymouth-quit-wait.service
      1.302s systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
      1.105s snapd.service
      1.004s dev-nvme0n1p1.device
       728ms fwupd.service
       662ms systemd-rfkill.service
       432ms mysql.service
       394ms udisks2.service
       377ms apparmor.service
       320ms upower.service
       318ms NetworkManager.service
       299ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-67.mount
       293ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1313.mount
       245ms snap-core18-1066.mount
       240ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-100.mount
       238ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-61.mount
       219ms dev-loop0.device
       217ms snap-core-7270.mount
       216ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-296.mount
       213ms apache2.service
       199ms networking.service
       184ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
```

Comment: During your fresh install, how did you prep the SSD for Ubuntu? Did you lay down a fresh GPT partition table? Do you have access to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB?

Comment: @heynnema Why, bless your heart.

Comment: Uhm, no. I did not do anything with the SSD before installing ubuntu. I'm really new to ubuntu so i might missed a lot of things. And yes, I do have access to Ubuntu bootable USB.

Comment: In the terminal type `systemd-analyze blame`. Copy the first screen and paste it into your question. Thanks,

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Added the information.

Answer (score 0):

15 seconds can be saved by removing `NetworkManager-wait-online.service` from the boot:

- [What does NetworkManager-wait-online.service do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018576/what-does-networkmanager-wait-online-service-do/1018731#1018731)

Not appearing in your question but worth checking is whether or not `fsck` is being run on every boot. If so you can change that to every 30 days or so:

- [Slow reboot - understanding fsck and tune2fs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219383/slow-reboot-understanding-fsck-and-tune2fs)

You can also completely turn off `fsck` during boot:

- [How to disable fsck run on Ubuntu 16.04 boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/797215/how-to-disable-fsck-run-on-ubuntu-16-04-boot)

Comment: Removing NetworkManager-wait-online.service sped up boot time a little bit but the stalls and random crashes while shutting down laptop still remains.